# GWT Greeting-Example not working / strange behavior

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am sorry for that vague title but I really don't have any idea what the problem is and where else I could look after it. I am creating a project named `test` and let Eclipse generate the default server-greeting example.

Everything works if I create a GWT project, right-click it and execute a "GWT Compile" command. Then my application is available at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Test.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` and gets displayed correctly so far -

> **but only if I go to** `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Test.html`. For some reason Chrome tells me to install the browser plugin for GWT if I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Test.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` even though the plugin is installed and running.

However, if I e.g. make any changes to the code like changing:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // ...
    RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
    RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);
    RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);
    // ...
}
```

to

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // ...
    RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
    //RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);
    RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);
    // ...
}
```

in the generated `Test.java` file the change is not reflected on the website. Not if I refresh the browser (Ctrl+F5) or clear the browser history explicitly.

Another strange thing is that I can not debug the Java code. If I set a break point somewhere in `onModuleLoad()` Eclipse does not stop there.

If I e.g. put a `System.out.println()` to the first line of `onModuleLoad()` I'm not getting that message either..

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    System.out.println("##########"); // Not working either
    // ...
}
```

Clicking on the "Reload web server" button that is provided by Eclipse in the Development Mode view does not help either. The only thing that works is re-compiling the whole project (which takes awfully long) but then only the content displayed gets updated - the break point does not get hit and `.println()` still does not output anything.

This gets really frustrating - does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know if you need further information to help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GWT DevMode browser plugins are deprecated; they no longer work in Firefox for more than a year, and in Chrome for a few months (depending on your OS); the only supported browser still is IE.
(in case you wonder: Firefox has been cutting access to some APIs needed by the plugin, and Chrome is shutting down support for NPAPI plugins altogether)

For a few versions, GWT has shipped a new DevMode called SuperDevMode that runs your code in JS. Starting with GWT 2.7, when you launch the DevMode you're actually using SuperDevMode with a new "compile on load" mode, unless you explicitly ask for the "classic" DevMode by passing a `-nosuperDevMode` argument.
GWT 2.7 comes with an incremental compiler, making the refreshes much faster than previously (even faster than "classic" DevMode in some –many– cases), and this is why SuperDevMode has been turned on by default.
Because the code is now compiled to JS, you no longer set breakpoints in your IDE, but in your browser's dev tools, using SourceMaps to see your Java code rather than the compiled JS. There's however a [plugin for Eclipse](https://sdbg.github.io/) that connects to Chrome using its remote debugging protocol so you can set breakpoints right in Eclipse; and IntelliJ IDEA has similar support.
No longer requiring a browser plugin however means that it runs everywhere, including your smartphone.
Last, but not least, SuperDevMode (aka CodeServer) overwrites your `*.nocache.js` with a specific one to get the "compile on load" behavior, so make sure you recompile your app before deploying to a server near you.

Comment: Ok now I get it. I went back to v2.6.0 because v2.7.0 does not support the GWT Designer. But of course v2.6.0 has a bug with the Designer and so I upgraded to v2.6.1. Now the Designer works - but of course - v2.7.0 has to be used because Chrome disables per default the Classic Dev Mode. So now I can decide if I go for v2.7.0 that "*should*" work but without GWT Designer support or between v2.6.1 that might or might not work in the future with Chrome. I hope they at least [reenable spacebar heating](http://xkcd.com/1172/) at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your application in debug mode(means anything you change and it  starts getting reflected to browser on reloading) you have to use URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/Test.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997. Above URL shows your server is running in dev mode supported by GWT. This dev mode of server enables you to debug the application. When you use only http://127.0.0.1:8888/Test.html, it shows you are working on web mode of server. This does not allow you to debug. So you have to re compile and re deploy your application to see the changes.
In brief GWT dev mode is required to debug the application. It is because actually you are trying to debug a javascript because everything you write in GWT finally gets converted to javascript after GWT compilation.

Comment: Okay, that is good to know and I already thought that this might be important somehow. But like I stated in my question - Chrome is being a D and thinks I have to install the Plugin again despite the fact that I got that already installed and running..